# React, style with if inside

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Currently I have this:

```
{data.map((row, i) =>
    <span style={{ backgroundColor: colors[i], color: '#fff' }}>{i + 1}</span>
    etc
```

But I need to decide the backGroun color depending on the `i`. When `i` be 0 I need to setup the color to red. I need something like this:

```
style={{ backgroundColor: { i === 0 ? red : colors[i] }, color: '#fff' }}
```

Of course that won't work, but how could I do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `backgroundColor` property should be either the string `'red'` or the variable `colors[i]`.

```
style={{ backgroundColor: i === 0 ? 'red' : colors[i], color: '#fff' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
style={{ backgroundColor: i === 0 ? ‌'red' : colors[i], color: '#fff' }}
```

Comment: thanks, same as Tholle, but you put it as an answer.

Comment: @pmiranda When I answered, nobody answered :) 2 min

Answer (score 0):

may this help you

```
'use strict';

const Test_span = (props) =>{

    const color = props.index==0 ? 'red':'white';

    return (
        <div>
            <span style={{backgroundColor: color}}>{props.number}</span>
            <br/>
        </div>
    )
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
    }

    render () {

        const temp = [10, 11, 12, 13]

        const data = temp.map((e, i)=>{
            return <Test_span number={e} index={i} key={e} />
        })

        return(
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {data}
                </ul>          
            </div>
        )
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just another Answer**

if (i === 0) is like to write if(!i)

```
style={{ backgroundColor: !i ? 'red' : colors[i], color: '#fff' }}
```

or

```
style={{ backgroundColor: i ? colors[i] : 'red', color: '#fff' }}
```

But I am jsut do not understand from whare the array colors came from.

and what the purpose of the i?

If I think a minute I can just put 'red' in colors[0], right?